# Will there any impact of Account Public read only to private in apex class failures

Tags: owd, with-sharing, without-sharing

We have OWD for Account as Public Read Only, but there is a requirement that we need to make an account for Private.
When we do that, the user will see only what they own and whatever they earn from other sharing settings.

But I need to know that there are a lot of classes that are using them with and without sharing modifiers, apart from limiting access. Will there be an impact on class failure? Do we need to do a functional test to verify that? Is anyone familiar with this kind of analysis?

Do we need to check one-by-one class for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Start by cloning sandbox from production
2. Change Account OWD to Private on sandbox
3. Run All Apex Test on sandbox, check for any errors in the apex test classes, get QAs to test if any functionalities are impacted.

If no errors, it is safe to change the OWD in Production.

If there are errors, fix the the sharing rules, apex classes, apex test classes, get QAs to test the functionalities again, etc until it is ready to be deployed back to Production

Comment: Thank you so much. It's a really valuable comment for me. We do need to check one by one class then right? I am freaking afraid because there will be something missing from my analysis. Thanks again.